# Find and remove nested level

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find and remove the value, where my **id is "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411"**

**my data:**

```
[
    {
        "products" : [ {
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411",
                    "quantity" : 1,
                    "totalPrice" : 100,
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de412",
                    "quantity" : 2,
                    "totalPrice" : 200,
                }
        ],
        "isCompleted" : false,
        "_id" : "5cc7e4096d7c2c1f03570a2f"
    },
    {
        "products" : [{
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de414",
                    "quantity" : 1,
                    "totalPrice" : 100,
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "5cc6d9737760963ea07de4133",
                    "quantity" : 2,
                    "totalPrice" : 200,
                }
        ],
        "isCompleted" : false,
        "_id" : "5cc7e4096d7c2c1f03570a2f"
    }

]
```

i tried:

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate({"products.id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411"},
{ $pull:  {"products.$.id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411"  })
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you don't need to use `.dot` notation. Instead you need to use "absolute" object structures:

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "products.id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411" },
  { "$pull": { "products": { "id": "5cc6d9737760963ea07de411" }}}
)
```

Comment: it will delete all the data inside products array not only single one.

Comment: Nopes your are not taking it correctly then. Working perfect with my mongo shell. Please post your query

Comment: I don't know but I'm doing exactly same.

Comment: Working on my robomongo and mongoose as well.